# Spring Integration - creating an anonymous queue

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, message-queue

**Problem:**
I am using Spring Integration backed by RabbitMQ.  I have a Fanout Exchange to which messages are published.  I wish to launch multiple instances of the same service which creates a queue bound to this exchange.  When a message is published to this exchange, I want all the launched services to receive the message.  This does not happen as although there are multiple services, they all use the same queue

**Solution:**
Create a non-durable, exclusive, anonymous queue for each consumer.

**Problem:**
How do I make the queue anonymous?

Here is my code so far, the problem is the binding requires a queue attribute, and the queue requires a name - and therefore is named, and not anonymous.

```
<rabbit:fanout-exchange id="structureUpdateExchange" name="publish.registry.update" >

    <rabbit:bindings>
        <rabbit:binding queue="publish.registry.update.queue"  />
    </rabbit:bindings>

</rabbit:fanout-exchange>

<rabbit:queue  durable="false" auto-delete="true" exclusive="true" name="publish.registry.update.queue"  />


<si:channel id="publishInformationChannel" />

<int-amqp:inbound-gateway request-channel="publishInformationChannel" 
                          queue-names="publish.registry.update.queue"  />
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Actually the queue does not require a name. You can create an anonymous queue simply with `<rabbit:queue id="..." />`. But the problem I am facing is that `<int-amqp:inbound-gateway />` requires the actual queue names, which I obviously don't know, because it's an anonymous queue...

Answer (score 1):

So yes, as has said by Phillipp define the queue with id but no name.

```
<rabbit:queue id="queueTemp"/>
```

You need to use SpEL to reference the queue name. See the queue-names attribute below:

```
<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter 
  channel="fromRabbit" 
  queue-names="#{@queueTemp.name}" 
  connection-factory="connectionFactory" />
```

You might already be doing this but note that on the consumer side you also define the fanout exchange with the binding to your temporary queue. So something like:

```
<rabbit:fanout-exchange id="myFanoutExchange" name="test-fanex" > 
  <rabbit:bindings>
    <rabbit:binding queue="queueTemp"  />
  </rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:fanout-exchange>
```

Comment: How can I use this queue with rabbit:listener ?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly define a channel that is backed by an AMQP queue:

```
<int-amqp:publish-subscribe-channel id="publishInformationChannel"
      exchange="publish.registry.update" />
```

This will create an exchange `publish.registry.update`, an anonymous queue and an incoming queue adapter for the channel `publishInformationChannel`.